# Make the text always be on top right of the box

Tags: html, css

Goal:
The text "test" should always be at top right of the box

Problem:
What code am I missing in order to fulfill the goal?

Info:
*The text "test" always should be top right no matter what size of the id="length"

Thank you!

```css
#length
{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}


#asdf {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
  <div id="length">
    
    <div id="asdf">
      test
    </div>
    aa<br/>
    bb<br/>
    cc<br/>
    dd<br/>
    ee<br/>
    ff<br/>
    <br/>

  </div>
```

Comment: Does it matter that the "aa" is in the same line with the "test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what u want to achieve, but you can check it:

```
#length
{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}


#asdf {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YOjKvR

Position relative to parent element and position absolute to "test" element

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your parent element should be relative so it becomes the new container for any absolutely positioned elements nested within. Remove height and width from #asdf to make it size to its contents.

```
#length
{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative
}

#asdf {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the css like this:

```
#length
{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}


#asdf {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}
```

You can add a "padding-top" to the #asdf if you want the "test" and "aa" strings in different lines.
Or another option:

```
#length {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#asdf {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
    display: inline-block;
}
.right{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}

<div id="length">
    <div class="right">

<div id="asdf">
      test
    </div>
    </div>
    aa<br>
    bb<br>
    cc<br>
    dd<br>
    ee<br>
    ff<br>
    <br>
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you put paragraph tags around your text, you'll have more control over how the text displays, as you can write css for the p tag.

The below snippet uses relative position, with negative margin top (of 5px)

```css
#length {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#asdf { 
  position: relative;
  top:5px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}

div>p{
position:relative;
float:right;
margin-top:-5px;

}
```

```html
<div id="length">

  <div id="asdf">
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
  aa
  <br/> bb
  <br/> cc
  <br/> dd
  <br/> ee
  <br/> ff
  <br/>
  <br/>

</div>
```

Comment: if you want to place the text box further right, you could increase the value of left, or use a high margin left or you could use the right: to position it

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!